# Allure report is not showing defects on web Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jenkins, allure

I just recently faced with an issue that Chrome does not open my Allure report (Defects tab) generated by Jenkins, however IE11 opens fine

I see the following JS error in Console:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$compile/tplrt?p0=allureTable&p1=templates%2Ftable%2Ftable.html
    at Error (native)
    at http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:60:173
    at http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:72:199
    at F (http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:100:187)
    at http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:101:350
    at k.$eval (http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:68)
    at k.$digest (http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:109:168)
    at k.$apply (http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:112:398)
    at h (http://mysite.example.com/jenkins/job/WebTestAutomation-UI/18/allure/webjars/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:72:454)
```

Changing version of Allure from 1.4.4 to 1.4.0 and below didn't help.
Does anyone face with that issue?

Comment: That seems to be a bug in allure-face. Please, send an issue to allure bug tracker https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues

Comment: Possible related with issue https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/448 Ensure that your web server does not use special modules which modifies own code. It can cause an exception like yours.